# Changing PHP file path in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

PHP is not working in any of my files. The `index.php` file in `htdocs` displays **Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(**. I found a possible solution in here, on the fourth post: https://theadminzone.com/threads/xampp-php-not-working.31448/. I don't know what "apache .conf" file to change and how I'm supposed to change it. How can I fix the PHP with this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to directory `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra` then open file `httpd-xampp.conf` and edit path directory PHP.

If you're not sure what that is, you can use this: https://pastebin.com/raw/G5UJ9ezL